# Photogate IR LED or laser

Tags: infrared, photodiode, phototransistor, laser-diode

Hi I am trying to build simple photo gate to measure speed of incoming ball. 
I decided I will use one photo gate with high frequency.

Because ball is much smaller then the box, which is comming in, I need to use more gates as on attached image.

1. Do I understand correctly that in this case I have to use some laser which sends centred light instead of IR LED diode which sends light in 120 degrees? I think that in case of IR LED the ball might not cover even one photo reciever.
2. Which element is better (faster) photo diode or photo transistor ?

Ball diameter is 3cm, max speed I need to read is oround 40 m/s

[image]

Comment: What diameter is the ball and what range of speeds do you expect to encounter?

Comment: You can get IR LED with narrow angle +/-5 degrees, and you can also place IR LED and IR diodes alternating.  At a distance of 15cm an area of FOV +/-5 degrees is +/- 1.3cm.

Comment: Google Ballistic Chronograph and you'll get some ideas [that actually work].

Comment: [This](http://www.network54.com/Forum/79537/message/1312148525/Poor+Man%27s+Electronic+Chronograph) must be the most ghetto version, but uses a pipe so basically limits the trajectory to 1D. You don't seem to have [in your post] a way constrain the ball to a 2D plane. It could well miss a laser etc.

Comment: http://bowmania.ru/tmp/chrono.pdf has bit more details on a more generally usable one (and some details about commercial ones too). Also see http://nutsvolts.texterity.com/nutsvolts/200906/?pg=36#pg36

Comment: @EMFields ball oround 3 cm, max speed is max 40 m/s

Answer (score 1):

For lowest cost of implementation you want to try using the IR LED and IR Detectors. Lasers would add expense that you really do not need for this.

Since the IR LEDs emit a wide spreading light pattern you have to devise a system to deal with that. This is typically done by pulsing the IR LEDs on one at a time and the repeat. During the time a specific IR LED is on you observe the output only from the IR Detector that is directly across from the IR LED. This gives you the selectivity that you need and eliminates the problem of multiple detectors picking up signals from the emitters. As long as you place the emitter/detector pairs close enough together you should be able to detect the ball sized object.

The challenge of a such system is selecting the components and designing the circuitry such that the multiplex rate of the emitter/detector pairs is quite a bit faster in time that the object you are trying to detect. Along with that performance goal will the taking a close look at whatever IR detector you hope to use and select one that does not have too long of detection time.

You can even make such system work as a grid by placing emitter/detector pairs across the box at right angles to what you have now. That would come into play if you needed to know just what region within the mouth of the box that the ball entered.

Comment: Laser diode like this http://i.imgur.com/1inj3X7.jpg cost 1.5 dollar , 5mW 650nm

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a CW laser, a couple of first-surface mirrors, and a photodiode in reverse bias mode.

Set the mirrors so they're parallel to each other on opposite sides of the box, position the laser so its beam is centered between and a little off normal to the long axes of the mirrors, (so that the beam zig-zags between the mirrors at a slight angle) and locate the photodiode at the end of the beam's path.

At 40m/s it'd take a 3cm ball 7.5 milliseconds to get through the beam, so that's easy enough to do. The angle of the zig-zags would determine the ultimate accuracy though, since if the circle of the  ball's circumference entered the beam's path in the space between a zig and a zag, the beam wouldn't be broken right away.

So, the smaller the angle the more like a curtain the beam would be.

Comment: Typical laser I can buy has 650nm, where visible light is from 380 -780, additionally, I can't find photo diode or photo transistor for 650nm but for whole range like 400-1100, so it would take day light, what do you recommend ?

Comment: Google "650mM photodiode" for many, many hits.